# vim own highlight with specific character

Tags: syntax, keyword, vim, highlight

I want my vim to highlight in red some keywords from the Pouet group like 'if(' in my .c files.
I figured out how to highlight if with:

```
syn keyword Pouet if
```

(This is my ~/.vim/syntax/c.vim)

and with

```
highlight Pouet term=NONE cterm=NONE Ctermfg=160 ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE
```

(And this is a part of my .vimrc)

The problem is,this code doesn't work with special characters like '(' or maybe a space or many spaces.
My question is: how do I make sentences like 'if(' highlight in red ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:syn keyword` only works for keyword characters (as defined by the `'iskeyword'` setting), and `(` usually is not contained.

You have to use `:syn match` instead, e.g.:

```
:syn match Pouet "\<if("
```

This is fine if you define your syntax all on your own. If you want this in addition to the existing C syntax highlighting, you need to analyze the original syntax groups and add stuff like `containedin=cConditional`, maybe you even have to modify the original syntax definition.

An alternative is `matchadd()`, which goes on top of the syntax highlighting:

```
:call matchadd('Pouet', '\<if(')
```

The problem here is that these matches are window-local, not bound to the filetype like syntax highlighting, so when you split windows or edit another filetype in the current window, the highlighting will be gone / will persist. These problems can be worked around with autocmds, but now it's getting really complex.